# How to link path from OpenAPI json file to a python function in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, openapi, fastapi

How to link path from OpenAPI JSON file to a python function in FastAPI.

Something I came to know about from StackOverflow was that we can use an external OpenAPI JSON file with fastapi using the following approach

```
app = FastAPI()

def custom_openapi():
    with open("api_spec.json", "r") as openapi:
        return json.load(openapi)


app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

The API spec has a single endpoint with parameters and their types.

How can I map the endpoint to a python function and get access to the parameters?

Comment: As far as I know you can't use the `openapi` parameter for anything like that - it just overrides the openapi json file returned from FastAPI. Instead you can use something like https://github.com/koxudaxi/fastapi-code-generator to generate a FastAPI API from a openapi.json file.

Answer (score 0):

To make an **API according to your existing OpenAPI**, in such a simple case (one endpoint), you need to:

**Create FastAPI app**:

```
application = FastAPI()
```

Make a router for your endpoint; here, you **assign the function to the API resource path**:

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return {
        "ping": "pong",
    }
```

**Register the router**

```
application.include_router(ping.router, tags=["Health"])
```

When registering, you can also use a parameter for API prefix, e.g., prefix="/accounts".

For **more complex APIs**, you can employ the [OpenAPI generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/python-fastapi).